# The use of a mixed conditional in context

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Tell me please if my sentence is grammatically correct.

> If you are hungry, eggs would be a nice choice to satiate hunger.

By using **would**, I tantively suggest that eggs are a great choice. Is that a correct use of a mixed conditional? By the way, *eggs are a great choice* or  *eggs is a great choice*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using the hypothetical in the second part of the sentence.

If you use *would*, the nuance is that you are suggesting a possibility rather simply making a statement of fact that is (so to speak) eternally true (i.e., eggs is *always* a nice choice).

But there's also nothing wrong with simply using *is*, if just presenting a fact is what you're after.

---

As for the subject-verb agreement part of the question, the subject of the sentence is *choice*, singular, so the verb is also singular.

It would be more apparent if you reversed the sentence:

> A nice ***choice*** **is** eggs.

*Eggs* is the object of the choice, not the subject of the sentence:

> It **is** eggs that I ***choose***.

Having said that, it's still common for people to use *are* rather than *is* in this case. Which means that it's somewhat *idiomatically* correct (in terms of actual usage), even if not syntactically correct. Most people would not find it strange to hear the plural used in *eggs are a good choice*. But if you're concerned with formal writing, it should be the singular.

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of [would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) is:

> "used with if in **conditional** sentences (sentences that refer to what
>   happens if something else happens)"
>   **For example** : 
>   If I'd had time, I would have gone to see Graham.

So, here, would is used to complete the "if" condition.

Comment: I am aware of that. I  asked about whether my use of "would" is valid.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope why do you think it's not valid?

Comment: Because the if clause is in the present

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope and "**would**" can be used with "**if**", as the example clearly depicts.